# how to generate automatic unique ID Number in Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, servlets

I want to create primary key on an entity named 'id'.  I want it to have an auto increment value generator on new persisted objects in our spring  project

Answer (score 1):

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
```